# ¿Cómo hago que una imagen apunte al ratón en canvas JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse

Estoy tratando de crear un juego en javascript en el que un perro deberia estar apuntando siempre al mouse y e buscado tutoriales en internet pero ninguno me a servido (todos eran de una cara que apunte al mouse) pero no puedo hacerlo.
no puedo poner mi codigo porque no puedo usar la imagen del perro :(

Comment: Si con "apunte" te refieres a que rote, puedes usar un transform:rotate y calcular el angulo del perro respecto el ratón usando trigonometría.

Comment: _no puedo usar la imagen del perro_ ¿?

Answer (score 5):

se que la pregunta debería ser borrada por no aportar nada ni una sola linea de código pero estaba entretenido el reto jejejeje.

```js
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  // Obtiene la posición del mouse
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;


// Obtiene la posición del perro
var dogX = document.getElementById("dog").offsetLeft;
var dogY = document.getElementById("dog").offsetTop;

// Calcula el ángulo entre el perro y el mouse
var angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - dogY, mouseX - dogX);

// Rota el perro hacia el mouse
document.getElementById("dog").style.transform = "rotate(" + toDegrees(angle) + "deg)";

});

function toDegrees(radians) {
  return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```

```css
#dog{
top:50px;
left:50px;
position: absolute;
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');

}
```

```html
<div id ="dog"> </div>
```

Comment: gracias, soy nuevo en stack overflow y no entiendo como poner el codigo en un comentario 